# And idiom for "You were right"

Tags: expressions, idiom-request

Is there an idiom to say "You were right", in a regretful way, when for example you didn't listen to what someone kept telling you and now he's proven to be right.
As in:

You were right about it. I shouldn't have done that.

Comment: One modern informal idiom is [**my bad**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/my_bad) used to acknowledge one's own mistake.

Comment: I don't know who voted to close as opinion based, but all word/phrase requests are opinion based in that there is usually more than one possible good answer. These questions are on topic which is why we have tags for them.

Answer (score 1):

When someone is proven right like this, the idiom (for them) is "I told you so!".  For you to say "You told me so" is slightly less of an idiom, perhaps, but would still be recognised, and it's the best I can think of.